# How to remove certain lines from a list file that contain a certain range of qualities/characters/values

Tags: r, list, awk, sed, terminal

Suppose I have the following list:

```
length_116609_cov_581.830645
length_95994_cov_638.256172
length_74141_cov_395.070508
length_58017_cov_410.981621
length_5022_cov_756.852071
length_4953_cov_57.127070
length_1520_cov_24.055039
length_872_cov_25.422104
length_435_cov_146.544586
length_243_cov_129.040984
length_192_cov_387.436620
```

And suppose I have ~20 more .list files that are the same in terms of the structure (ie., length_#_ cov_#), but contain different "length" and "cov" values, and may also have a different total number of lines per list.

If I would like to remove all lines that contain a length value of under 500 from all lists in a directory at once, how would I do this? I am somewhat familiar with the command line in terminal and with R, so ideally I would learn how to deal with this issue using one of these but I am open to any method.

Thank you!

Comment: You could use `separate()` from tidyr and then filter all values less than 500 outside your data.

Answer (score 1):

We can extract the digits after the `length_`, convert to numeric, create a logical vector with `>=` to subset the vector

```
v1[as.numeric(sub("length_(\\d+)_.*", "\\1", v1)) >= 500]
#[1] "length_116609_cov_581.830645" "length_95994_cov_638.256172"  "length_74141_cov_395.070508" 
#[4] "length_58017_cov_410.981621"  "length_5022_cov_756.852071"   "length_4953_cov_57.127070"   
#[7] "length_1520_cov_24.055039"    "length_872_cov_25.422104"
```

or using `parse_number`

```
v1[readr::parse_number(v1) >= 500]
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("length_116609_cov_581.830645", "length_95994_cov_638.256172", 
"length_74141_cov_395.070508", "length_58017_cov_410.981621", 
"length_5022_cov_756.852071", "length_4953_cov_57.127070", 
"length_1520_cov_24.055039", 
"length_872_cov_25.422104", "length_435_cov_146.544586", 
"length_243_cov_129.040984", 
"length_192_cov_387.436620")
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `awk`, you could update inplace all files with

```
awk -i inplace -F_ '$2>500' *.lst
```

or

```
for f in *.lst; do
    awk -F_ '$2>500' "$f" > tmp && mv tmp "$f"
done
```

if your `awk` version does not support the inplace parameter (older than `4.1`)

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `sed`:

```
sed -i -E '/length_0*([0-9]{1,2}|[1-4][0-9]{2})_/d' *.lst
```